# How to modify clickable elements in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why doesn't the on click listener work after clicking on the first list-button?

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/1203y34b/)

```
$(".acceptTask").on("click", function(){
acceptTask(this);
});

$(".solveTask").on("click", function() {
solveTask(this);
});

function solveTask(e){
...
}

function acceptTask(e){
...
$(document).on("click", ".solveTask", solveTask);
}
```

Comment: why do you have the seconde listener there? this: $(document).on("click", ".solveTask", solveTask);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('.solveTask').on('click', /*...*/)` only applies the event handler to anything that has a class "solveTask" at that time. So when you add the `solveTask` class in your `acceptTask` function, add an event listener.

```
$(e).addClass('btn-warning solveTask')
    .click(function () { solveTask(this); });
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1203y34b/1/

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem previously and used 'delegate' instead of 'on':

```
$(document).delegate('.solveTask', 'click', solveTask)
```